# Loading table view with data with 2 different prototype cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to populate a tableView with different prototype cells at different times. The problem is any code after `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MeArticlesCell") as? MeArticlesCell else {return UITableViewCell()}` isn't being called and I can't figure out why. Im returning the correct amount of rows.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(postsSelected){
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? feedMessagesCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        //the code in this part loads posts fine

    } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? feedMessagesCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        //this part never gets called 
    }
}
```

Comment: when you write `//this part never gets called` you are speaking of the `guard let` statement? Or what comes after?

Comment: correction: it does get called but nothing after that line is called

Comment: try to `print(postsSelected)` before the if statement. It will most likelly always be true, and therefore never going into the `else` statement

Comment: that isn't the issue I already checked

Comment: Then we need more infos. "This part never gets called" can be figured out just by printing something in this `else` statement.

Comment: Oh I didnt saw your edit

Comment: I set a break point after the guard let in the else statement and never breaks

Comment: see my answer, you enter the `else` part of the `guard` statement ending the function right away, most likely due to a cast problem

Comment: how do I fix the second guard let to fix the casting problem

Comment: You are not using 2 different prototype cells. Both are same `feedMessagesCell` cells with same identifier `messageCell`

Comment: nope, both are different cells with different classes and different identifiers

Comment: @tHatpart feedMessagesCell is the first cell and second cell also feedMessagesCell

Comment: first try using `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` method. secondly, its the same cell in both if and else. same id same class, so how you say it's different. second time it returns nil so if goes to `return UITableViewCell()` this

Comment: I just noticed that, someone must have edited that way. The issue was I was using MeArticlesCell for the identifier in code but MeArticleCell in storyboard, it worked but now i'm dealing with the issue of different sizing of those cells

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `guard` statement fails and goes into the `else` part.

```
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? feedMessagesCell else { // this fails 
       // enters here
       return UITableViewCell()
       // exist the function - nothing will be run after
    }
```

My guess is it fails to **cast** your it as a `feedMessagesCell`, so `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messageCell") as? feedMessagesCell` makes `cell` to be nil ( and then enter the `else` part )

Comment: that part works its the second guard let that fails

Comment: They re both identical in your example though. 
The problem remains the same: nothing will be run after a guard statement fails that is what it design to do. Check what fail in your init/cast and you are good to go

Comment: I just noticed that, someone probably changed it in an edit. The issue was I was using MeArticlesCell for the identifier in code but MeArticleCell in storyboard, it worked but now i'm dealing with the issue of different sizing of those cells

Answer (score 0):

You're using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` method to init cell which return `nil` if it doesn't find any reusable cell. [More here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell)

> A UITableViewCell object with the associated identifier or nil if no
>   such object exists in the reusable-cell queue.

You should use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` which init a new cell if it doesn't find any cell for reuse. [More here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell)

> A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This
>   method always returns a valid cell.